# Using PostgreSQL functions in a QGIS Plugin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, pgrouting

I'm planning to write a QGIS plugin which calculates isochrones.

I have created an tested a network in PostgreSQL and now I want to create a plugin. The Idea is to use a point layer as input and calculate isochrones using the network and nodes I've already created

In PostgreSQL I used the pgDrivingDistance function and alphashape for the calculation of the isochrones.

Is there a way of using the pg function in a QGIS Plugin or are there any other Ideas how to implement a function with the same function as pgDrivingDistance?

Comment: whats your code so far? There are modules from pyqt which allows you to connect to the database and perform queries on it

Comment: I haven´t started to write any code at the moment. I will take a look at pyqt and keep you updated... thanks

Comment: You Can also use psycopg2 for that.

Answer (score 1):

There exists already a pgRouting plugin for QGIS: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgRoutingLayer

It has implemented also the driving distance function, but it needs to be upgraded to work with the new QGIS 3. Contributions to this plugin are always welcome!

Comment: It´s not exactly what I want, but a very weclome input indeed. Thank you